# How to integrate custom R/Python code with KNIME?

Tags: r, rstudio, knime

I am good in R and recently started learning KNIME tool. I have developed multiple custom codes in R and Python. Now I would like to integrate R/Python custom code with KNIME tool. Is this possible to integrate? If so, Please explain me how to integrate them?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You need to set set up preferences in KNIME to your local R/Python installation and run code in dedicated nodes for R/Python.

Here is link to official [Python instructions](https://docs.knime.com/2019-06/python_installation_guide/index.html).
Here is link to nice [R instructions](https://forum.knime.com/t/install-r-alongside-knime-on-windows-and-macos/13287) from KNIME Forum.